# Convert Pointer To Member Function To Pointer To Static Function

Tags: c++

How do I convert a member function pointer to a static function?

Here is my code:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    int n;
    void func();
};
void ClassA::func()
{
    n = 89;
}

class ClassB
{
public:
    float f1;
    float f2;
    void func(float f);
};
void ClassB::func( float f )
{
    f1 += f;
    f2 += f;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    ClassA* a = new ClassA;
    ClassB* b = new ClassB;

    //PROBLEM IS HERE
    void (* pf_func1)(void*) = ClassA.func;
    void (* pf_func2)(void*, float) = ClassB.func;


    pf_func1(a);
    pf_func2(b, 10);
}
```

Comment: There are various mistakes in that code snippet, missing `;` after classes declarations, using `new` instead of just putting the variable on the stack, using `ClassA.func` instead of `ClassA::func`... I suggest you start with learning about C++ from a good book or university course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) it to an instance of the relevant class:

```
auto func1 = std::bind(&ClassA::func, a);
func1();
```

This binds the member function `Class::func` to `a`. And similarly:

```
auto func2 = std::bind(&ClassB::func, b, std::placeholders::_1);
func2(10.0f);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) to allow you to easily change the object that it is called on, providing the syntax that you asked for:

```
auto func1 = std::mem_fn(&ClassA::func);
func1(a);
auto func2 = std::mem_fn(&ClassB::func);
func2(b, 10.0f);
```

Not that in both cases `func1` and `func2` aren't actually function pointers, but they do behave like them. The types returned from `std::bind` and `std::mem_fn` are implementation defined. They are both, however, convertable to a `std::function`.

Comment: You're incredibly fast. I was just starting typing.

Comment: Note: `std::bind` is a C++11 feature; if your compiler is too old for that you can use `boost::bind` instead.

Comment: @UFNHGGI Then perhaps use `boost::bind` and `BOOST_AUTO`.

Answer (score -1):

```
void(ClassA::*pf1)() = &ClassA::func;
void(ClassB::*pf2)(float) = &ClassB::func;
void (__thiscall * pf_func1)(void*) = (void (__thiscall *)(void*)) ((void*&)pf1);
void (__thiscall * pf_func2)(void*, float) = (void (__thiscall *)(void*, float)) ((void*&)pf2);
```

**SOLVED**

:)

Comment: This is undefined behavior. It may stop working at any time. For example, if you use multiple inheritance.

Comment: This is absolutely true.
Why the negative rating :((

Comment: Um, because it's the wrong answer, and if somebody else tries it, their code may crash?