# Is it good practice to cast a pointer to a member function as a pointer to a C function

Tags: c++, pointers, pthreads

This code compiles (with g++ (GCC) 6.3.1) and appears to "work". But I'm VERY skeptical as to whether it constitutes ***good practice***.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


class ThreadObj
{
  public:
    void *memberFunction(void*);
    void startThread(void);
  static int w;
};

int ThreadObj::w = 13;

void* ThreadObj::memberFunction(void*)
{
  w = 17;
  return 0;
}

void  ThreadObj::startThread(void)
{
  void * (*p)(void *) = *((void * (*)(void *))&ThreadObj::memberFunction);
  pthread_t    tid;

  if (pthread_create(&tid, 0, p, this) == 0)
    pthread_detach(tid);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  ThreadObj thr;
  thr.startThread();

  return 0;
}
```

Casting a pointer to a member function as a pointer to a C function and passing `this` as data seems to rely (TOO MUCH) upon the mercies of how the compiler chooses to interpret/compile this.

This has been covered before but not definitively answered.

How can this example be broken?

Comment: You tagged this as `C`, but there are no such things as member functions in `C`.

Comment: It is broken because casting pointer to functions of different types is undefined behavior.

Comment: Any use of a function pointer cast with `reinterpret_cast` (or equivalent C cast) other than to cast back to the original type is undefined behavior by definition. See `7)` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Explanation). This isn't so much about good practices as it is not allowed in c++. What you *can* do is define a new static method that accepts a pointer to an instance of the class, and use a function pointer to that method instead.

Comment: Note that this may be a good starting point for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040654/convert-pointer-to-member-function-to-pointer-to-static-function if you mix it with c++11 thread support.

Comment: It doesn't constitute good practice.  The example is broken without anything needing to be done to it — it is relying on undefined behaviour.

Comment: I suggest using std::thread instead. Then, instantiating a thread with a member function is easy, and well-defined. On most (all?) unix OS:es, std::thread uses pthreads under the hood anyway.

Comment: Definitely not. This is undefined behaviour and in practice *will not work* as soon as you try to access a non-static member variable.

Answer (score 1):

The old way (with recent syntax) to go were:

```
class ThreadObj
{
public:
    void memberFunction() { w = 17;}
    void startThread() {
        pthread_t    tid;

        if (pthread_create(&tid, 0, &Func, this) == 0) {
            pthread_detach(tid);
        }
    }
    static void* Func(void* p) {
        auto* that = static_cast<ThreadObj*>(p);
        that->memberFunction();
        return nullptr;
    }
private:
    int w = 13;
};
```

But in c++11, `std::thread` has a better interface.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  It's undefined behavior.  It is rather cute though.  Whether it works or not is kind of up in the air.  My guess is that it generally would.

The author of the code is taking advantage of the fact that `this` is generally passed in as the first parameter to the implementation of member functions.

Answer (score 0):

Using pointer to methods of a classe is very usefull and, for me, is a good  practice because it allows you implements another kind of patterns, for example: trigger a event over severas class that has the same prototype of method.

Answering your question: It is a matter of designe and how it will be usefull for your goal.

I share you a code where i create tow thread over diferents methods of the same class, i hope you it will help you.

https://github.com/jorgemedra/C-11-Threads/blob/master/README.md